# RabbitMQ maxed out the number of files on the filesystem and cannot start

Tags: ubuntu, rabbitmq

Our rabbitmq node just went down and cannot restart.  When logging into the server and executing:

`df -i`

it reveals the following:

`Filesystem     Inodes  IUsed  IFree IUse% Mounted on
udev           503283    360 502923    1% /dev
tmpfs          505605    437 505168    1% /run
/dev/xvda1     655360 655360      0  100% /
tmpfs          505605      1 505604    1% /dev/shm
tmpfs          505605      3 505602    1% /run/lock
tmpfs          505605     16 505589    1% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs          505605      4 505601    1% /run/user/1000`

How does one remove the erroneous files so that rabbitmq created so it can be started?  As of now, nothing can happen as I receive many `No space left on device` errors.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

The default data directory for RabbitMQ is `/var/lib/rabbitmq`. You can delete it and it should free up inodes, but be warned that you will lose all messages and configuration and will basically be starting from scratch.